# C++ Abstract classes and creating derived classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class, overriding

1) I want to create an abstract class which two derived classes can inherit all of the abstract methods and NOT have to override any behaviour. This means I have no pure virtual function to force the subclasses to provide. Does this mean I cannot create an abstract class (I know in Java I can)?

2) I am a little unsure how I create my derived classes, considering I have a constructor for the abstract class- but what is the purpose of this constructor? Should I be explicitly calling it from anywhere??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can still make it abstract. The idiomatic thing to do is to make the destructor pure virtual. (Note, that despite being pure virtual you will still need to provide a definition for the destructor.)

E.g.

```
struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() = 0;

    virtual void fn1();
    virtual void fn2();
    // ...
};
```

If you want to call a non-default constructor from your derived class constructor you need to use the member initialization list. E.g.

```
Derived::Derived() : Base(0, 1.5, "hello") {
}
```

If you are just calling the default constructor of the base class, you can usually leave this out and the default base constructor will be called automatically when an instance of any derived class is constructed.

Answer (score 1):

1) In C++ you don't have to define the class as abstract or anything. You can extend **any** class you want, if you don't want to override function behaviour, you don't even have to mark the methods as virtual. If they're `protected` or `public`, they'll be accessible in the derived classes.

2) The constructor of the base class will be called without your command, before the constructor of the derived class.

Answer (score 1):

1) Declare your destructor as pure virtual:

```
virtual ~BaseClass() = 0;
```

2) You can call it from the derived classes' constructors' initialization lists, but if it's a default constructor, it will be called automatically. Remember - to initialize a derived object, you must first initialize its base class part (which is done automatically for you by calling the base class's constructor, in case of a default constructor).